# Retrieving an image from Parse with Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm trying to retrieve an image and text from Parse. I'm able to retrieve the saved text but not the image. What am I doing wrong? Below is the code for the function that I want to retrieve the image. Thanks in advance.

```
func showImage() {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Description")
    query.orderByDescending("ceatedAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        self.imageArray = [UIImage]()
        if let objects = objects {
            for imageObject in objects {

                let userImage: UIImage? = (imageObject as! PFObject)["UserPhoto"] as? UIImage
                if userImage != nil {
                    self.imageArray.append(userImage!)
                }
            }

        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's tricky at first, but it gets a lot easier. Here's the code to make it work:

```
    let userImage = (imageObject as! PFObject)["UserPhoto"] as! PFFile 


    userImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (imageData, error) -> Void in


        if error == nil {
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)

            self.imageArray.append(userImage!)

        } else {}
        }}
```

the issue is that parse stores images as `PFFiles`, they're not directly images yet, think of it more as a URL than anything. You have to **download** the image, and then do something with it to make it work. You can't just directly cast it as a UIImage.

One thing to note (because this gave me trouble a while ago) is that the `.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` method is asynchronous, so it'll run on it's own, and your code will continue before it's completed. Another thing to get used to.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks! I'm still not getting the image back on the table view... is there something I need to do with Storyboard? Like create a UIImageView and connect the image I'm trying to download to it?

Comment: Absolutely! I'd have to know more about your code to give any more advice. If you wanna make custom cells for a tableview, you're gonna need to look up a tutorial on how to do so, and then work on integrating the code above to give the tableview cells their pictures. You're on the right track now though.